# images sometimes default to 0 width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a site for a client using bootstrap and for some reason the images I use in my nav-icons don't always appear.

When I first load the page, I notice that the images don't appear and have a width of 0. If you re-load the page the images show up.

Is there something going on here or something I can do to make sure they are always there and don't have that hiccup?

**Here is my code for the `nav-bar`:**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-collapse text-center navbar-expand-lg mt-4 navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler nav-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon float-right"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-0" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav algin-items-center d-flex ml-5 pl-5">
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center expand-lg"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <img src="images/shapeimage_1.png" width="26" height="26" class="nav-ico after my-auto" />
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center" id="about"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                <img src="images/dogpaw_1.png" width="26" height="26" class="nav-ico after my-auto" />
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center" id="services"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
                <img src="images/icon-bowl_46.png" width="26" height="26" class="nav-ico after my-auto" />
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center id="adopt""><a href="#" class="nav-link">Adopt</a></li>
                <img src="images/heart2_3.png" width="26" height="26" class="nav-ico after my-auto" />          
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center" id="donate"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Donate</a></li>
                <img src="images/icon-house_46_1.png" width="26" height="26" class="nav-ico after my-auto" />           
                <li class="nav-item col-2 text-center" id="events"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Events</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The images between the **`li`** are what sometimes change width.

I typically open in chrome and the developer tools show that the image is there and unbroken, but has a width of 0.

Reload the page and they are there without any problems and generally remain there for each re-load unless I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and force a full load from the server.

Comment: If the network is not working properly, loading the image (high-quality or large image) will not work properly even if the Chrome load icon is displayed.

Comment: As I can remember, Bootstrap forces items in <li> to have no space between them.
May you provide url so I could check that?

Comment: www.al-van.org/jake is the working directory. Would it make more sense to add them as list items? I have some script that removes them at the 760 breakpoint when it collapses into a hamburger menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looking at the comments and doing some trial and error, it seems simply adding `<li>` to the img tag is enough to make them consistently stay put. They still collapse at my breakpoint and work as I want them to without any obvious side effects. Thank you @Bogdan Lapchenkov for the idea and the suggestion. I'd up your answer if it were an answer mate.